# JavaScript EJB variable field holding value?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json, dom

I have an ajax enabled list of records that I'm going through and each one has a dropdown box that I'm trying to make a required field for the form to submit. To complicate matters the 'Close Record' button is not the submit button so I can't just use required attribute on the select(dropdown box) that I'm using.  The value for the selected dropdown box is saved in an Enterprise Java Bean so I thought I could just write a JavaScript function to check the value:

```
function CheckForm() {
    var clearObj = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    if(clearObj.value != "") {
       return true;
    } else {
       clearObj.style.backgroundColor ='yellow';
    }
    return false;
}
```

This doesn't work because once I close one and go to the next it's maintaining the value of the previous record on the page. Basically I have an update-content event that I need to know how to handle. Any ideas as to how to manipulate the DOM or JSON object to make this select a required field? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the little information given, I would assume that when you close the existing record and then loading the next record, you are doing it through an ajax request. If thats the case, then you can add a call back for the ajax request, which would reset the drop down.

This should be a comment, but as you see, I dont have 50 points :-)

Comment: VasamsettyCan you give an example of a callback?

Comment: Please see the link -- http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_callback.asp if you are using plain javascript. If you are using any javascript framework, please consult the related documentation.